# SSIS: How to store master-details records by condition?

Tags: ssis, conditional-statements, one-to-many, master-detail, dataflow

I'm new to SSIS and I completely stuck with perhaps easy question.
I have two tables with one-to-many relationship. I parse HTML data in a Script component and create two outputs for Master Data and Detail records.
[image]

Then I check the condition for overwriting the existing data, and if it is satisfied, I write Master record to the table. Unfortunately, my data flow looks like on the picture above (schematic view). Detail records are added in any case. I would like the Details are stored only if the condition is met (the green arrow on the picture), but can't imagine how to do it.

Comment: what's the condition or how is it determined if you should write the master data?  Depending on if this condition can be moved prior to the script task or set within the script task you can just use expression constrained precedence. to do that within the script add a package variable that you can set the value of in the script and then test for its value in the constraint.

Comment: Hi @Matt! Condition here is only to illustrate the problem. Real structure is more complex. But thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys!
Eventually I managed to resolve the problem. I split the whole process in two data flows. In the first one I parse html, save master data in table if needed and save parsed detail data in the package Object variable. Also, the first data flow has a Row Count component which saves its value in MasterRowCount variable. In the second data flow I save the detail data in table. The first and the second data flows are connected by expression constrained precedence (@MasterRowCount > 0). Thus, the second data flow executes only if the master data were added.

Answer (score 1):

I have face the same problem when we have to load the XML data into parent child tables. For this , I have added two data flow tasks in package. In first DFT, I have parsed XML and loaded data into master table only. In second DFT, I have parsed child XML nodes data and pass this output to merge join operator (first input). Now, we have to pass second input to merge join operator, for which i have extract data from master table.

[image: Master table insertion -]

[image: Child table insertion -]

Comment: I got the idea. One that I don't like is that XML would be parsed two times. In my case the source is a remote web page. But I'll think how to overcome it. May be transfer the html nodes between the data flows as an Object variable.